# Python TKinter Text Getting Index from Mouse Click?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an application I'm developing in Tkinter that requires me to get the index of a mouse click inside a tk.Text() widget. How can I do this? Specifically, I am NOT looking for coordinates, but rather the actual character index of the string in the text. I want to then add a char at that index (thus changing the text) and updating the tk.Text() widget.

Comment: One of the forms of indexing you can use with Text widgets is `@x,y` to specify the character closest to those coordinates.  You can use this directly with `.get()` to retrieve that character, or with `.index()` to convert it to canonical `line,column` form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jasonharper already suggested, you can use `text.index("@x,y")` or you can even use `text.index("current")`

minimal example:

```py
from tkinter import *


def handle(event):
    print(text.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}"), text.index("current"))

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.bind("<Button-1>", handle)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "current" (I'm guessing tk.CURRENT is the same thing?) did the trick. Still have to convert from the "lineNumber.charPosition" format to a straight char index for my string, but that's totally doable. Thank you both!

Comment: @TheMathBoi yes it is the same.

Comment: @TheMathBoi: you can use the text widget's `count` method to count the number of characters between any two indexes.